# Retrofit to GraphQL

Tags: java, android, graphql, retrofit2, aws-appsync

I have an Android app that will be using data from GraphQL API via `AWS Appsync`. I know most resources point to `Apollo` as the client library to use, but due to our CICD, generating the models is not entirely possible, or I haven't found good examples/documentation on CICD/Apollo/Android. The work around was to create a regular `POST` request with `Retrofit`. No matter what I try I can't seem to get anything other than a 400 returned. I have successfully called the API with `curl` and `NodeJS`. I am fairly new to Android so any guidance is appreciated.

curl approach (success):

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/graphql" -H "x-api-key:[SOME_API_KEY]" -d '{ "query": "query { listData { dataName } }" }' https://amazon.endpoint.com/graphql
```

Node approach (success):

```js
async function testApi() {
    const headers = {
        'x-api-key': 'SOME_API_KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/graphql'
    }

    const options = {
        headers
      };

    try {
        const b = await axios.post('https://amazon.endpoint.com/graphql',
        { "query": "query { listData { dataName } }" },options)
        console.log(b.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

testApi();
```

Android approach (failure):

```java
// class to create
public interface GraphqlService {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/graphql",
            "x-api-key: SOME_API_KEY"
    })
    @POST("/graphql")
    Call<String> getLockers(@Body String body);
}
```

```java
// in main code
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://amazon.endpoint.com")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
GraphqlService service = retrofit.create(GraphqlService.class);

try {
    JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
    String query = "query { listData { dataName } }";
    paramObject.put("query", query);
    service.getLockers(paramObject.toString())
            .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
            });
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am thinking there is something funny at work with the way Gson converts the object? I have verified that the query is right via `curl` and `Node`. Once again I am new to Android development and would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue. It was with the use of the Gson objects. Instead of using `String` I should have been using `JsonObject` from (Gson). Since I was using the `GsonConverterFactory` there were weird values showing up when using the `JSONObject` creator. Hopefully this helps someone out. Also working with Gson, the default class that should be used when serializing objects is `JsonObject`.